# Two equal strings in python don't match each other

Tags: python, string

I have two lists of strings and i'm trying to find equal strings.
'Text' is a list from pandas dataframe, previously loaded from txt file.
'Check' is a list from txt file, it's summary of strings of 'Text'

```
text=list(sub_df['sentence_text'].values)
myfile=open(file,'r', encoding='UTF-8')
data=myfile.readlines()

for check in text:
    flag=False
        for line in data:
            if check.strip()==line.strip():
                print('TRUE')
```

where: data and text - lists of strings I definitely know that there are 7 equal strings, but "True" condition print fewer. I wonder if i print equal strings in console and compare them with "==", everything is ok.

i'm totally nuts))

**UPDATE:**
The problem is solving easily, thanks a lot to all participants! You need to use:

```
print(repr(check))
print(repr(line))
```

And you will see that problem is in spaces '/xa0' (UTF-8 encoding)

Comment: try `str(check.strip().lower()) == str(line.strip().lower())` or much easier as `if check.strip().lower() in data`. My point is that you might be comparing different types or different letter cases.

Comment: Just do `print(repr(check))` and `print(repr(line))` and you'll see

Comment: @LordSalforis, thank you. But results stayed the same. I even tried to read strings from two txt-files and compare, but results are the same

Comment: can you provide a [mcve], including data to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @jamylak, you're my savior))  Thanks a lot, the problem was in '\xa0' utf-symblos

Comment: Try using `ipdb` debugger. Below `for line in data`, put `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace();`. You'll need to install it as `$ pip install ipdb`. Then when you execute your program, you'll be able to check if what is inside the variables in the current loop. Try `> type(line)` or `> type(check)` to see their types or just print them `> line` or `> check`.